# I lose numbers when I put a Div inside a Numbered List

Tags: html, list, html-lists

I am trying to put a div inside a numbered list, something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <div>
        <li></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

And after the div tag, I lose the numbers, they transform into a bullet list. 
How can I keep track of the numbers?

Comment: You can't wrap `<li>` elements in divs or anything other than `<ul>` or  `<ol>`. The browser fixes the HTML and creates a new list for the invalid list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write any functionality for this div the put div inside li like

```
`<li>
   <div></div>
</li>`
```

And
If you want to perform any functionality for the li then simply give the id to that li and work on further.

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal html , you cannot have a div in that position
You need to do

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li><div></div></li>
</ul>
```